# Alert when pandas DataFrame changes (observer)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Essentially I'm looking to create an observer pattern based on a DataFrame. I'd like to add some call/alert everytime the DataFrame changes.

pandas DataFrames aren't a simple object. Any pandas experts know a method that is called everytime a DataFrame changes (regardless of whether it's index assignment, row operations, etc.)?

Already did a cursory review here but nothing sticks out:
[DataFrame](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/a1b6587153ebf81b02272fc8a717d2b6c9d0c4aa/pandas/core/frame.py);
[NDFrame](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/53bc3ca5f931fb8e9262cf944dfb127435fa7241/pandas/core/generic.py)